# Prestashop 1.7: Quantities can not be saved in the creation of a new product

Tags: php, module, prestashop-1.7

Good morning all,

I created a module that allows to add a product to the frontoffice. Even though it adds a new product it is still showing some problems:

1. When I got to the backoffice catalog->products->myProduct, the quantity shows 0 (when it should be at 99999)
2. When I do a search (through the search bar), I can’t find my product, and the product no appears in supplier page.

If somebody can help me resolve this issues, it will be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks

```
public function testAddNewProduct(){
        // Add new product
        $object = new Product();
        $object->name = array(1=> "my product test", 2=> "my product test", 3 => "my product test");
        $object->description = array(1 => "Quanta autem vis amicitiae sit, ex hoc intellegi maxime potest.", 2 => "Quanta autem vis amicitiae sit, ex hoc intellegi maxime potest.", 3 => "Quanta autem vis amicitiae sit, ex hoc intellegi maxime potest.");
        $object->description_short = array(1 => "Quanta autem vis amicitiae sit, ex hoc intellegi maxime potest.", 2 => "Quanta autem vis amicitiae sit, ex hoc intellegi maxime potest.", 3 => "Quanta autem vis amicitiae sit, ex hoc intellegi maxime potest.");
        $object->category =  array(0 => 16);
        $object->price = 15;
        $object->id_tax_rules_group = 1;
        $object->id_category = 17;
        $object->id_category_default = 17;
        $object->link_rewrite = array(1 => "my-product-test", 2 => "my-product-test", 3 => "my-product-test" );
        $object->id_manufacturer = 0;
        $object->id_supplier = 41;
        $object->id_manufacturer=2;
        $object->quantity = 9999;
        $object->minimal_quantity = 1;
        $object->additional_shipping_cost = 0; 
        $object->wholesale_price = 0;
        $object->ecotax = 0;
        $object->width = 0;
        $object->height = 0;
        $object->depth = 0;
        $object->weight = 0;
        $object->out_of_stock = 1;
        $object->active = 1;
        $object->available_for_order = 1;
        $object->show_price = 1;
        $object->on_sale = 0;
        $object->online_only = 0;
        $object->redirect_type = '404';
        $object->reference = 'demo';
        $object->meta_title = array(1=> "my product test", 2=> "my product test", 3 => "my product test");
        $object->meta_keywords = '';
        $object->meta_description = array(1 => "Quanta autem vis amicitiae sit, ex hoc intellegi maxime potest.", 2 => "Quanta autem vis amicitiae sit, ex hoc intellegi maxime potest.", 3 => "Quanta autem vis amicitiae sit, ex hoc intellegi maxime potest.");
        $object->id_shop_default = $this->context->shop->id;

        if(($object->validateFields(false, true)) === true &&
            ($object->validateFieldsLang(false, true)) === true &&
            $object->add())
            {
                $object->updateCategories($object->category, true);
                echo 'ok'; exit;
            }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

The field quantity in the product is not used to keep track of the stock. Maybe it was in the beginning. So after you added the product, you need to add the stock of that product. If you use the "normal" (most common used) stock feature you can use the function:

```
StockAvailable::setQuantity($id_product, $id_product_attribute, $quantity, $id_shop = null)
```

If you use the StockManager (advanced stock management system), you need to add the stock in a different way.

```
StockManager->addProduct($id_product, $id_product_attribute = 0, Warehouse $warehouse, $quantity, $id_stock_mvt_reason, $price_te, $is_usable = true,  $id_supply_order = null, $employee = null    )
```